# Unable to import files with custom UTI extension on IOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, import, ios13

Since the update to IOS 13 importing custom UTI files is not working (works perfectly on devices with 12.4)

I've downloaded the simple working project form this page: https://www.raywenderlich.com/813044-uiactivityviewcontroller-tutorial-sharing-data , which i also used as a base for the sharing system of my app.

On IOS 13 (12.4 works), when get the sample file (from email o data folder) and click on Copy To App, IOS goes back to the main screen, and after a few seconds i get a Safari crash error.

This is the project info.plist section for exporting files:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Book Tracker Document</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>book_320.png</string>
                <string>book_64.png</string>
                <string>book_44.png</string>
                <string>book_22.png</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.raywenderlich.BookTracker.btkr</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <string>btkr</string>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <string>application/booktracker</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</key>
```

Things i tried:

- Add an UTImportedTypeDeclarations, with the same details as UTExportedTypeDeclarations ones as there is none in the project ---- STILL CRASH
- In this [post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118932) about at the end, was suggested to remove the section from the info.plist (Not modifying the Document Types section) and create it anew from the interface  ---- STILL CRASH (it also causes an infinite loop in xcode when adding array items for public.filneame-extension or mime-type)
- Various combinations of the solutions above

This is the main error i always get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Full log is here: [log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sfW6-sfC2uj4jlFEKY1BpzLWyL5YKFe7/view?usp=sharing)

I'm kind of out out ideas! Please help!

Comment: can you please add the crash detail here .

Comment: This is a link to the error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sfW6-sfC2uj4jlFEKY1BpzLWyL5YKFe7/view?usp=sharing

```
Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer to your question but I have a similar problem with this same sample app from Ray Wenderlich.  Unfortunately the comment section for this tutorial is closed.

I am using the "finished" version which has all the UTI information already set.

In my case I want to save the ".btkr" document to the Files application.  That works OK but then if I tap on the .btkr document saved in Files, it opens the BookTracker application but quietly fails in the Book.swift importData(from url: URL) method.

I unraveled the guard statement into do/try/catch blocks and what I see is "The file “New Book.btkr” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."  This is being thrown from the "let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)" statement.

The odd thing is if I share the same document via eMail, a tap on the .btkr attachment successfully opens the app and imports the .btkr just fine.  Share via AirDrop works as well.

I do not know if this is only an iOS 13 bug because I no longer have any devices with older iOS's.  Since the tutorials from Wenderlich are generally very good (this one is from February 2019, before iOS 13) I suspect your problem and my problem are iOS 13 bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing exactly the same thing here on my app. Wrapping readFromURL and writeToURL in between startAccessingSecurityScopedResource & stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource helped on my iPad running iOS 13.2.3, but I'm still seeing the Safari crash and unable to open the documents on the iPhone running 13.2.2.